# Connecting external domain name to AWS S3 website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I want to host a static website on Amazon S3. Created the relevant buckets - testing them ok. 
Now I have a domain name i've registered with EuroDNS - www.gopropel.io - I can't find how to connect it to my AWS S3 bucket. Do I need to create a route 53 hosted zone? Went over the AWS documentation and they all assume you are registering your domain with them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools, or other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to route to host a static website without using S3.

1. Go to your S3 console and select your bucket.
2. Select the "Properties" tab, then select "Static web hosting".
3. Once this is setup you should see an endpoint url. Similar to this: "Endpoint :
   http://xxxx.yyy.s3-website.xxxx.amazonaws.com"
4. Copy this url then create a CNAME record with EuroDNS and paste this link as the alias for "@" & "www" (optional). In the case of Eurodns set the host to your domain (gopropel.io & www.gopropel.io) and the canonical name as the url.

Allow a few minutes for the effect to go through and your domain should resolve to the s3 bucket.

This is not an ideal solution as it will limit certain features such as SSL (HTTPS).

The recommended approach is to go with Route53 it should cost less than $1.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I followed the steps and added the CNAME record in EuroDNS. However I then get an error from EuroDNS - "A CNAME record is not allowed to coexist with any other record on the same host in accordance with RFC 1912 section 2.4". Any idea? I would happily switch to Route53 (I will need https in the future), not sure how I would map an existing domain to them...

Comment: @VLVL This usually occurs when another record matches the CNAME. Check to see if any other records, most likely an A record, contain gopropel.io or www.gopropel.io. Remove these records, then try to add the CNAME. If this doesn't work please send a screenshot of your dns records (omitting any sensitive data if required).

Comment: @RishiSerumadar CNAME records cannot be used at the apex `@` of a dns zone.  That is not a valid configuration, and is why Route 53 offers Alias `A` and `AAAA` record configuration. Alias is not a record type, it's an internal lookup.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I hadn't realised this is an internal lookup.@VLVL At this point the best way is to migrate to route 53. However, you can setup a redirect or simply setup an A record that resolves to a domain and forwards the traffic to a www record pointing to the s3 bucket.

Comment: @VLVL note that you do not have to actually transfer the domain registration to the Route 53 Registrar in order to use Route 53 in order to use a Route 53 hosted zone to host the records for your domain.  You can leave it where it is registered now, and transfer it later or not at all.  The only required step is making a Route 53 hosted zone the authoritative source for your domain.  See [Making Amazon Route 53 the DNS Service for an Existing Domain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html).